# 32 bit PPC rlwinm instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, instruction-set, powerpc

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the `rlwinm` PPC Assembly instruction (Rotate Left Word Immediate Then AND with Mask).

I am trying to reverse this part of a function

```
rlwinm r3, r3, 0, 28, 28
```

I already know what `r3` is. `r3` in this case is a 4 byte integer but I am not sure exactly what this instruction `rlwinm` is doing to it.

By the way, this is on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Have you looked at an instruction set reference? The first zero is the shift, and the two `28` operands are the start and end of the mask (which is a sequence of `1` bits, so clearly not the value `28`).

Comment: [PowerPC instruction set reference](http://www.ds.ewi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in1006/instruction-set/)

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is not *quite* right. As per the [IBM link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_rlwinm_rlinm_rtlwrdimm_instrs.htm) on this instruction, the form you're seeing is:

```
rlwinm <target=r3>, <source=r3>, <shift=0>, <begin-mask=28>, <end-mask=28>
```

Hence no actual shift is involved. And the actual mask used for the `AND` operation is constructed from the `begin` and `end` mask *positions,* it's not given as an explicit argument<sup>(a)</sup>.

In this case, since both positions are 28, the mask is simply a single bit, as per the linked page (slightly paraphrased):

> If the *begin-mask* value is less than the *end-mask* value plus one, then the mask bits between and including the starting point and the end point are set to ones. All other bits are set to zeros.

So the instruction you're seeing is nothing more complicated than a single `AND` operation.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There *is* a form that allows you to specify the actual mask (assuming it consists of contiguous one-bits) but it's the *four*-argument version and really just syntactic sugar that the assembler can turn into the five-argument one.

Comment: Note that PowerPC counts bits from MSB=0, unlike other architectures.  So the AND mask is `1U<<(31-28)` in C notation.

Answer (score 2):

@paxdiablo's answer is a correct, but to add some more context:

The various `r*` instructions (rlwinm, rlwimi, etc) are designed for extracting bit fields whose size is known at compile time, for example C struct bitfields, or even just splitting a word into bytes (which may be faster with one `lw` and four `rlwinm` instructions than several separate `lbzu`s).

```
lw r4, r3 ; load the word at the address pointed at by r3
rlwinm r5, r4, 8, 24, 31 ; first byte in r5
rlwinm r6, r4, 16, 24, 31 ; second byte in r6
rlwinm r7, r4, 24, 24, 31 ; third byte in r7
rlwinm r8, r4, 0, 24, 31 ; fourth byte in r8, identical to andi r8, r4, 255
```

The `rlwinm` instructions can also be used, as in this case, as a special form of `andi` for contiguous sets of bits. Since instructions in PowerPC are always 32 bits, instructions taking immediate values have only 16 bits to hold those values - so if you want to mask a set of bits that crosses the high/low half-word boundary, say 23 to 8, you need to use multiple operations.

```
lis r4, r4, 0x00ff ; first set bits 23 to 16 of the mask
ori r4, r4, 0xff00 ; then bits bits 15 to 8
and r3, r3, r4 ; then perform the actual masking
```

However, with the `rlwinm` instructions, we can perform that same operation in a single instruction:

```
rlwinm r3, r3, 0, 8, 23
```

In your case, the value probably holds flags for something and this instruction is extracting one of them. The next instruction is probably a conditional branch on `r3`.

ETA: Peter Cordes corrected out some of my mistakes, for which I am grateful, and added that it was probably unnecessary to use `rlwinm` in this case, and that it may simply be a peculiarity of the compiler that causes this instruction to be generated instead of `andi`.

Comment: Also, PowerPC counts bits from MSB=0, so the mask is `1<<(31-28)` for a 32-bit machine.  In 64-bit mode, bit 28 would be in the upper half of a 64-bit register, which is why PowerPC has different versions of these instructions for 64-bit mode.  gcc seems to always use `rlwinm` whenever possible, only using `andi` when the mask isn't a contiguous group of 1-bits.

Comment: Thanks! it's actually been a while, so I appreciate it getting checked over.

Comment: If you have time, I'd highly recommend going back and rewriting the parts of the answer that were wrong, and adding a note about how PowerPC numbers bits.  You want the answer to be right in the first place, rather than wrong + corrections.  Then it would be worthy of an upvote, IMO.  Everyone can see the edit history if they want, and the goal on SO is for the current version of an answer to be the best it can.